# Inline Babel script: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have [this JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mx0jLt2u/1/) with some React. Most of the code in the fiddle is not relevant, except for this part:

```
class TodoApp extends Component {
    render() {
    return {
        <div>
        <button onClick={() => {
            store.dispatch({
            type: 'ADD_TODO',
            text: 'Test',
            id: nextTodoId++
          })
        }}>
            Add Todo
        </button>
        <ul>
            {this.props.todos.map(todo =>
            <li key={todo.id}>
                {todo.text}
            </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    }
  }
}
```

When this is interpreted, I get this error in the browser:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Inline Babel script: Unexpected token (130:5)
  128 |     render() {
  129 |     return {
> 130 |         <div>
      |         ^
```

I don't understand why the JSX is not recognised.

I have added this to the HTML part:

```
<script src="https:// fb.me /react-0.14.3.js"></script>
<script src="https:// fb.me /react-dom-0.14.3.js"></script>
```

Since I am getting the React and React DOM scripts(I added some spaces to the URLs, otherwise I would not have been able to post the question), the JSX code should be properly interpreted, right?

Comment: Could you list babel plugin that you used? AFAIK, React and react dom doesnt interpreted jsx files. Its the work of babel.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using `{` and `}` around your JSX, you should be using `(` and `)`:

```
return (
        <div>
        ...
        </div>
       );
```

[Fixed Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mx0jLt2u/2/) *(it has other issues that are revealed when you click Add Todo, but the syntax error is fixed)*

That's if you want to use anything around it at all; it isn't necessary, but is common. This is also valid:

```
return <div>
    ...
    </div>;
```

The reason you see `(...)` so much is that this is **NOT** correct but sadly results in a silent failure:

```
// NOT CORRECT
return
    <div>
    ...
    </div>;
```

It's because of (the horror that is) Automatic Semicolon Insertion, which will insert a `;` after the `return`, making it:

```
// NOT CORRECT
return;
    <div>
    ...
    </div>;
```

E.g., `return;` followed by a `React.createElement` call that never gets executed.